# URL rewriting....what am I doing wrong?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

please help me with this one... I am really new to this subject.
I have placed this in my .htaccess file.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/?$ viewgallery.php?cid=1 [NC,L]

To make the link

http://www.123456.com/viewgallery.php?cid=1

look like this...

http://www.123456.com/viewgallery/1/

What I am doing wrong... ? It is not working...

Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

You're rewriting "gallery/1/" instead of viewgallery.

`RewriteRule ^viewgallery/([0-9]+)/?$ viewgallery.php?cid=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Paimoe, I tried that also but it still not working... I wonder why? Should I add anything else other than these two lines in .htaccess file?  RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^viewgallery/([0-9]+)/?$ viewgallery.php?cid=1 [NC,L]

Comment: What do you mean not working? What error comes up? Internal server error or 404?

Comment: Paimoe... no errors are shown... and it doesn't change the links at all. I see no changes and the link continues to work as before. Am I supposed to add anything else to the .htaccess file? Because all I have is these two lines above in it....thanks again fro the replies...

Comment: Ok.. you mean on the page itself? Rewrites don't change those, they enable the ability to use the seo urls. try and visit site.com/viewgallery/1/ in your browser and see if the proper page loads.

Comment: Thank you...I was dead wrong about everything... I see what you are saying now.It does really bring up the page when I try what you said but it doesn't brings up the background...somehow it looks like , it leaves the .css file unrecognized. On another note...what does change the actual URL...? How can we do that? Does this mean REWRITE is only for the Search Engine Optimization? Thank you for your time...

Comment: You would manually change the links, so <a href="/viewgallery/1/">link</a> for example. The CSS probably won't work because of relative vs absolute links. <link href="stylesheet.css" /> would look for it at site.com/viewgallery/1/stylesheet.css, which doesn't exist. Best is to set the "href" to "/stylesheet.css" and check it all works properly.

Comment: Paimoe... I hope I am not bugging you too much about this. But how do we change the actual link that shows up on the browser like this "123456.com/viewgallery.php?cid=2&pid=236 How can we change that and the viewer will see something simple like 123456.com/gallery/2/236 Is it possible to do so?